# Problema com acentuação - R

Tags: r, acentuação

Tento resolver o problema dos acentos com esse script:

```
Mapa@data$NAME_2 <- Mapa@data$NAME_2 %>% 
      as.character() %>% 
      stri_trans_general("Latin-ASCII") %>% 
      toupper()
```

Mas, quando abro a coluna `NAME_2`, o nome dos municípios fica, por exemplo: 
MACEIA³ ao invés de MACEIÓ ou MACEIO.
`Mapa@data$NAME_2` é uma coluna com o nome dos municípios do Brasil.

Comment: Qual comando está utilizando para ler os dados? Você precisa setar o encoding para "utf-8".

Answer (score 2):

```r
# Instalar o pacote abjutils, se ainda não tiver instalado:
# install.packages("abjutils")

library(abjutils)
x <- c("maceió", "acentuação")
rm_accent(x)
#> [1] "maceio"     "acentuacao"

Created on 2018-06-27 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).
```

Ou, neste tópico tem outras respostas: [Remover acentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46473/remover-acentos/48761)

Answer (score 0):

Teste isso:

```
#Ajustando codificação de caracters do dataset
df = apply(Mapa@data, 2, as.character) 
Encoding(df) = "UTF-8"
Mapa@data = as.data.frame(df)
```

Comment: Eu já havia tentado isso, infelizmente não funcionou. :(

Comment: Verifique o banco de dados, pode ser que o erro não esteja na leitura pelo R, e sim no arquivo de dados.