# Como identificar o número da página de um .pdf por algo escrito nela?

Tags: r, pdf

Eu tenho um .pdf com 120 páginas, cada página é um certificado e a única diferença entre eles é o nome do participante.

Eu também tenho um .csv com a lista de nomes e o e-mail dos participantes (usei esta lista para gerar o .pdf e vou tentar usar os e-mail para mandar pelo R)

Como eu consigo separar cada página (certificado) em um novo .pdf e salvar com o nome do participante?

Vi funções como `pdf_subset` da `library(pdftools)`, mas como eu consigo identificar o número da página por algo escrito nela?

```
library(pdftools)

# extair paginas de 1 
pdf_subset('certificados.pdf',
           pages = 1, output = "Carlos dos Santos.pdf")
```

É um trabalho bastante repetitivo, não gostaria de fazer manualmente.

Também pensei em separar página por página e depois procurar o nome no .pdf e alterar o nome do arquivo. Mas também não sei como fazer isso ainda.

Segue modelo de certificado:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iwgW6kMT7C9Xee5SM65vz-D8B26bpavz/view?usp=sharing

Exemplo de .csv:

```
nome,email
Prof. Dr. Thiado Souza,thiado@uol.com
Prof. Dr. Marcelo José,mjose@gmail
Ricado Augusto,augustor@terra.com
Carlos José,cajose@ig.com.br
```

Comment: Fala @RxT, blz? Vc tem o `.pdf`  para disponibilizar? Pode ser um fake (ou com nomes omitidos), aí posso tentar algum código. Só que como você quer "separar cada página (certificado) em um novo .pdf", eu penso que é mais fácil fazer via terminal de comando. Vc usa ubuntu? O Ubuntu tem o ImageMagick que deve fazer isso de forma fácil (eu só não sei como faria esse loop de cada página, mas é questão de pesquisar). E dps disso, imagino que o resto é mais fácil.

Comment: @GuilhermeParreira obrigado pela atenção! Adicionei o arquivo na pergunta ! Sim, uso o Mint na verdade, mas não deve ser diferente, né?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendo em vista que os certificados seguem a mesma ordem do arquivo csv:

```
library(pdftools)

arq <- read.csv('./rxt.csv')
nomes <- as.character(arq$nome)

cria_pdf <- function(n, i){
  pdf_subset('certificado-teste.pdf',
             pages = i, output = paste(n[i],'.pdf'))
}

lapply(seq_along(nomes),cria_pdf, n = nomes)
```

Este cria no diretório arquivos separados baseado na listagem dos nomes do csv.

Answer (score -1):

Creio que a função seguinte divide o pdf de entrada em páginas, guardando cada página num ficheiro e renomeia esses ficheiros com os nomes do ficheiro csv. A entrada da função é

1. `file` - o nome do ficheiro pdf;
2. `nomes` - o data.frame com uma coluna `'nome'`

Precisa do pacote `pdftools` para processar os ficheiros pdf e do pacote `stringi` para remover acentos e letras especiais, tal como etá [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254381/82237).

```
library(pdftools)

rename_file <- function(from, to){
  out <- tryCatch(file.rename(from, to),
                  error = function(e) e
  )
  if(inherits(out, "error")){
    out <- tryCatch(file.copy(from, to),
                    error = function(e) e,
                    warning = function(w) w
    )
    if(inherits(out, "error")){
      stop(e)
    }
    if(inherits(out, "warning")){
      warning(out)
      out <- FALSE
    }
    if(file.exists(to)) {
      if(file.exists(from)) unlink(from)
      out <- TRUE
    } else out <- FALSE
  }
  out
}

fun_split_pdf <- function(file, nomes){
  # ler os dados do pdf para uma lista de data.frames
  data_list <- pdf_data(file)
  # ficar com a coluna 'text' de cada data.frame da lista
  # e convertê-la em um único vetor com paste()
  Text <- unlist(lapply(data_list, function(x) paste(x[['text']], collapse = ' ')))
  # se tiver acentos, removê-los
  Text <- stringi::stri_trans_general(Text, "Latin-ASCII")
  # agora ver quais nomes do csv estão em qual página do pdf
  i <- sapply(nomes[['nome']], function(x){
    x <- stringi::stri_trans_general(x, "Latin-ASCII")
    j <- grep(x, Text)
    if(length(j) > 1) j[1] else j
  })
  # ordenar a coluna 'nome' do csv pela ordem do grep
  nms <- nomes[['nome']][i]
  # nomes finais dos ficheiros de saída
  nms <- paste0(nms, '.pdf')

  # fazer o split para um diretório temporário
  tmp <- tempfile()
  pdf_split(file, output = tmp)

  # renomear os ficheiros temporários
  pattern <- paste0(basename(tmp), "_.*\\.pdf")
  tmp_fls <- list.files(path = dirname(tmp), pattern = pattern)
  tmp_fls <- file.path(dirname(tmp), tmp_fls)
  sapply(seq_along(tmp_fls), function(i){
    rename_file(tmp_fls[[i]], nms[[i]])
  })
}

fl <- list.files(pattern = '\\.pdf')
fl
#[1] "certificado-teste.pdf"

nomes <- read.csv("pdf_teste.csv")

fun_split_pdf(fl, nomes)
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: Estou tendo esse erro: `Error in nomes[["nome"]][i] : tipo de subscrito inválido 'list'` mas a coluna "nome" é charactere.

Comment: @RxT O que é que `print(i)` logo a seguir ao `sapply` dá? Se der uma lista e não um vetor, faça `i <- unlist(i)` logo a seguir ao `sapply`.

Comment: Ele retorno o nome e as posições $`Nome e sobrenome`
[1] 1

$`Outro nome e sobrenome`
[1] 2    -------- se colocar o `i<-unlist(i)`, eu tenho esse erro: `Error in file.rename(tmp_fls, nms) : 
  'from' and 'to' are of different lengths` e eu percebi, que algumas pessoas se cadastraram duas vezes. Esse pode ser o erro?

Comment: @RxT Pode ser. Talvez `i <- unique(unlist(i))` resolva o problema. Não pode postar um link para um ficheiro com essa situação de cadastros repetidos?

Comment: Removendo os repetidos ou utilizando o `unique()` o resultado está sendo `FALSE` para todos os valores.

Comment: Aplicando sua resposta nos exemplos que postei, tive a mensagem: `Warning messages:
1: In file.rename(tmp_fls, nms) :
  não foi possível renomear o arquivo '/tmp/RtmpwzCKgS/file7e8e15c01a2e_0001.pdf' para 'Prof. Dr. Thiado Souza.pdf', motivo 'Link entre dispositivos inválido'`

Comment: @RxT Isso é uma mensagem de erro do sistema. Uma solução é copiar para o arquivo destino e depois `unlink` o arquivo original. Neste momento não posso postar código, amanhã de manhã (Portugal é GMT) de certeza que posso.

Comment: @RxT Afinal não foi ontem, veja agora.